# Postgres as default database in Processmaker

Tags: postgresql, pdo, processmaker

By default Processmaker 3.0.1.8 uses MYSQL database. We don't want to increase our work of maintaining two databases. we cannot let go Postgres but to use Processmaker we need to also use Mysql. Is there anyone who has used ProcessMaker 3.0.1.8 with postgres 9.2+.

Comment: http://wiki.processmaker.com/3.0/Database_Connections

Comment: I read from their forum that to use postgresql, there will be a huge rewrite of the PHP code. Therefore, their code was tuned for mysql database from the beginning and not through sql abstraction.

The solution is you can still use postgresql by means of scripts and variables and save them to external database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ProcessMaker does not currently work with Postgres as the core application database.

This is something that is being considered for the next version, 4.0, however no official decision has yet to be made.

So, for now, if you want to use ProcessMaker, it has to be on a MySQL database.

Answer (score 1):

ProcessMaker 4 now works with Postgres, MySQL, and MS SQL, so we recommend you migrate to it if you are interested in using Postgres.  You can get the source on github:  [ProcessMaker Open Source](https://github.com/ProcessMaker/processmaker)